# Problema Iphone PhoneGap Build

Tags: phonegap, iphone

Para hacer una consulta en la base de datos externa, obtener y mostrar los resultados, lo hago así:

```js
function municipios() {
  archivoValidacion = "http://www.appnecrofagas.com/municipios.php?jsoncallback=?";
  
  $.getJSON( archivoValidacion, {} ).done(function( respuestaServer ) {
    if ( respuestaServer.validacion == "ok" ) {
      $( "#municipio" ).html( respuestaServer.contra );
    } else {
      /// ejecutar una conducta cuando la validacion falla
    }
  });
}
```

Me funciona perfectamente, tanto en la web, como en android. Pero, en **iOS** no hay manera de que funcione, ¿alguien sabe a qué puede deberse?